# Getting error as "list index out of range". Need to delete duplicate elements from list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, duplicates, element

```
list = [1, 2, 6, 2, 9, 8, 1]
   for i in range(0, len(list)):
     for j in range(1, len(list)):
        if list[i] == list[j]:
          list.pop(j)
          print(list)
```

I have tried by using this code

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while iterating over it and don't call your list `list`.

Comment: Why dont you use set(your_list_name), it will remove all the duplicate elements as ->set<- by nature is unique